# Does a receptionist need permisssion of secretary to transfer calls to a director?

Tags: professionalism, first-job, phone

If someone calls, looking for the director of the company, am I right to transfer the call straight to the director? Or should I first get permission from the director's secretary?

Comment: You should consider revising your question to use workplace appropriate grammar and punctuation.  It is an excellent practice to get oneself into.

Comment: I've cleaned up your writing, but also voted to close because this is a company-specific practice. Some may insist that calls to a director actually go to the director's secretary. Others may expect you to ask some questions to determine whether the call goes to the secretary or the director. Still others may expect you to contact the secretary and discuss the answers to those questions, then decide together where the call goes, and so on. Nobody here knows your company's policy, and our advice about what "makes sense" won't help you if your policy is not what we think it should be.

Comment: Have you asked any of the following: the director, the director's secretary, or your immediate supervisor? If so, what did they say? If not, why not?

Comment: The answer will also be specific to the situation. Even if you know your director doesn't normally want calls, what do you do if something unusual happens, like say a family member calls with a family emergency, the secretary is not there, etc. Still, having a policy in place is a good starting place, but we can't tell you what that policy is or should be.

Comment: I've called places and been transferred several times. Seems to be common practice. So I would say, send it up the chain. Let it be someone else's problem.

Answer (score 3):

This answer depends entirely upon company policy. First job new concept: Ask questions to those who you work with.  Make the questions clear and to the point.

Comment: It may not even be uniform company policy. Different senior managers may want calls handled differently.

Comment: Agreed, there are many ways for this to be handled within a company but more of the point was its a company specific thing, not something you ask the internet.